# codeigniter - multiple dropdowns & display of results on the same url

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I have two dropdowns, Tournaments & Categories.
The output of view would be something like this:

```
<select id="tournament">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Tournament1</option>
<option value="2">Tournament2</option>
<option value="3">Tournament3</option>
</select> 

<select id="category">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Category1</option>
<option value="2">Category2</option>
<option value="3">Category3</option>
</select>
```

The values of options are fetched from a db table. On this table I have relations between Tournament and Category. Its records look something like this:

tournament_id category_id team_id ...

```
        1           1       1
        1           1       2
        1           1       3
        2           1       4
        2           2       5
        2           3       6
```

What I want to do is, when "Tournament" dropdown changes, let's say from 1 to 2, then dropdown "Category" should be updated with new values (step1) and below displayed records with results (e.g. team name, wins, etc.) (step2). That means, the url 
(localhost/ci/results/) should not change.

I figured out how to make the step1, following this tutorial:
[dynamic_dependent_dropdown_filtering_with_codeigniter_and_jquery](http://mikeheavers.com/main/code-item/dynamic_dependent_dropdown_filtering_with_codeigniter_and_jquery),
but stuck on step2.

I suppose, somehow I have to trigger with jquery the controller and then the view, so that it displays new records after some change in any of the two dropdowns.

Any help or hints on how to do this would be appreciated.

Basically, I need something like this:

[motogp results](http://www.motogp.com/en/Results+Statistics)

---

Update #1:

This is my Controller (results.php):

```
class Results extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("tournaments_model");
}

function index(){
    $data['mytitle'] = 'Results';

    if($this->input->post('tournaments')){
        $tournament_id = $this->input->post('tournaments');
    }else{
        $tournament_id=1;
    }

    if($this->input->post('categories')){
        $category_id = $this->input->post('categories');
    }else{
        $category_id=1;
    }

    $data['tournaments'] = $this->tournaments_model->getTournaments();
    $data['categories'] = $this->tournaments_model->getCategories($tournament_id);

    $data['rows'] = $this->tournaments_model->getAll($tournament_id, $category_id);

    if($data['rows']>0){
        $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('results_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');   
    }else{
        $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('norecords_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }   
}

function postCategory($tournament_id)
{
    $this->load->model("tournaments_model");
    $data['categories'] = $this->tournaments_model->getCategories($this->input->post('tournaments'));
    $data['categories'] = json_encode($data['categories']);
    $this->load->view('jsonCategory_view', $data);
}
```

This is the view (results_view.php):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Tournament</td>
<td>
<?php 
echo '<form id="frmTCG"  action="'; echo base_url().'results/" method="post" name="frmTCG"/>';

foreach($tournaments as $r){
 $opTournament[$r->tournament_id] = $r->tournament_name;
}

if(isset($_POST['tournaments'])){
 echo form_dropdown('tournaments', $opTournament, $_POST['tournaments'], 'id="tournament"');
}else{
 echo form_dropdown('tournaments', $opTournament, null, 'id="tournament"');
}

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<?php 
foreach($categories as $r){
 $opCategory[$r->category_id] = $r->category_name;
}

if(isset($_POST['categories'])){
 echo form_dropdown('categories', $opCategory, $_POST['categories'], 'id="category"');                   
}else{
 echo form_dropdown('categories', $opCategory, null, 'id="category"');                   
}
?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

This is the jquery (called from footer_view):

```
$('#tournament').change(function(){
var tournament_id = $('#tournament').val();

if (tournament_id != ""){

    var post_url = "results/postCategory/" + tournament_id;
    //var post_url = "results/";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: post_url,
         //data:     $('#tournament').serialize(),     
         data:  $('#frmTCG').serialize(),// 
         dataType: 'json',


         success: function(data) 
          {

            $('#category').empty();
            $('#category').show();

               $.each(data,function(id, name) 
               {                    
                var opt = $('<option />'); 
                  opt.val(id);
                  opt.text(name);

                  $('#category').append(opt); 

                });

           }, //end success
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("getTestData failed with textStatus '" + textStatus + "' errorThrown '" + errorThrown + "'");
    }

     });

} 
}); //end change    

$('#category').change(function(){
  var category_id = $('#category').val();

  if (category_id != ""){
       var post_url = "results/postCategory/" + category_id;
    ...same as $('#tournament').change()
}
```

The problem is that the $tournament_id and $category_id in index(), never get updated, they don't get values from $_POST[], which means getAll() won't bring new records.

So, after the change in any of two dropdowns, how can I force it to call again index() of my controller? Thank you.

Comment: this has not much to do with codeigniter, it's just ajax. your ajax view should generate a json result set, and then the JS code should update the page.

Answer (score 0):

As Karoly said, this is a problem for ajax.

Create a function in your controller that returns the categories for the tournament

```
function ajax_return_categories($tournament_id = NULL)
{
    if($tournament_id != NULL)
    {
         $this->db->select('categories')->from('db_table')->where('category_id',$tournament_id);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return json_encode($query->result_array());
    }
}
```

and call it from with ajax when the first dropdown is changed

```
$('#tournament').change(function(){
    var tournament_id = this.value;
    var result = $.get('/tournament_controller/ajax_return_categories/'+tournament_id);
    $.each(result, function(val, text) {
        $('#category').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
    });
})
```

something like that.

---

update:

If you want the data on the page to update based on the dropdown selection and you don't want the URL to change, you need to use ajax to request and populate the data.

create a function in your result.php controller that returns the results:

```
function get_results($tournament_id = NULL, $category_id = NULL){

    $data['rows'] = $this->tournaments_model->getAll($tournament_id, $category_id);

    if($data['rows']>0){
        $this->load->view('results_view', $data);
    }else{
        $this->load->view('norecords_view');
    }   
}
```

and call it when the dropdown changes

```
$('#tournament').change(function(){
    var tournament_id = this.value;
    var result_table = $.get('/tournament_controller/get_results/'+tournament_id);
    $('#results_holder').html(result_table);
    var result = $.get('/tournament_controller/ajax_return_categories/'+tournament_id);
    $.each(result, function(val, text) {
        $('#category').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
    });
})
```

Comment: Same principal applies. Create a codeigniter method to generate the code you want to insert on the page and call and insert it with ajax.